# Styling/images/tables in email templates

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to do the following things in an email template for Dynamics CRM online:

- Change the default font
- Insert an image
- Have a table/multi-column layout

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. There two ways to achieve this:

1. Using Design Tool on UI. You can change Font Name, Font Size, and Font Color with buttons on the UI Tool. However, there is no controls to insert Image, Table, or other stuffs. To achieve this, you can create your template somewhere else in HTML, and copy-paste the result to template create form. [More here](http://www.elvenprogrammer.org/stunning-html-rich-emails-dynamics-crm-2011/) and [here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2014/07/08/easily-create-html-emails-microsoft-dynamics-crm-via-powermailchimp/).
2. Another way is to create a workflow which is triggered when a template pre-creation. And update the template body with your HTML template.

Hope it helps!